# How to make background scale from center outwards with CSS transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to replicate the effect when you hover over a date with Material UI's date picker [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) (click on any text input to trigger the picker, then hover over a day) where the background expands outwards from the center.

I've tried to copy the CSS from here, but I've only managed to get the opposite working. See: https://jsfiddle.net/2zkofa0x/3/

My CSS:

```
span:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 151, 167, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;
}
```

Would anyone know how I can have the coloured background spread out and fill from the center of the element (opposite of what I've got above)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try like this. It puts the hover effect on a parent div so the hit target is always there.

Also, the circle needs to start off at a scale of 0 so it can expand to the full size during the transition.

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='circle'>
  </div>
  <span>42</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

div.container > div.circle {    
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 450ms ease 0ms;
}

div.container:hover > div.circle {
  background: rgba(0, 151, 167, .5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;
}

div.container span {    
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

div.container:hover span {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2zkofa0x/18/

Comment: put the `transition` property in the non-hover state to apply the animation to transition out too.

Comment: @jkris good call. I have added the transition to the non-hover state as well

Answer (score 2):

Use `box-shadow`

```css
li { position: relative; display: inline-block; padding: 10px; }
li:before {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #18b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #18b;
  transition: all .3s;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
li:hover:before {  
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #18b;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. You could also use jquery to get the same effect.

```css
/* Material style */
button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 360px;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  background: #2196F3;
}

/* Ripple magic */
button{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40);
  }
}

button:focus:not(:active)::after {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}


/* On Hover */
.ripple-button1{
 position:relative;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background-color:#99C;
 color:#FFF;
 border-radius:360px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;
 display:table-cell;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.wave1{
 position:absolute;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background-color:#FFF;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 transform: scale(0);
 opacity:0.5;
 border-radius:300px;
}

.ripple-button1:hover > .wave1{
 animation: ripple-in1 2s;
}
 
@keyframes ripple-in1 {
 0% {transform: scale(0);}
 20%{transform: scale(1);opacity:0.3;}
 100%{transform: scale(1);opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<h3>Ripple on Click</h3>
<button>Click !</button>
<h3>Ripple on Hover</h3>
<a href="#" class="ripple-button1"><div class="wave1"></div>Hover !</a>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is a bit different to what I want to do. I only want to use CSS transitions. Like to avoid keyframes if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same. Thank you for raising. Though you have already chosen an answer, I'll share my hack which looks similar to the one on the quoted page.

```css
div {
  margin: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center; //Fix the element to center
}

span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 151, 167, 0.5);
  padding: 15px; //Transform padding, width and height instead of border-radius
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 1ms;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>42</span>
</div>
```